# Regex with multiple groups

Tags: java, regex

I have the following single line string

```
10101010110001
```

I want to capture all 0s between 1s

I used the following regex:

```
/(10+1)/
```

this gave me the following groups:

1. 101
2. 101
3. 10001

which is not what I want, I want all groups(even if 1 already captured on the previous group):

1. 101
2. 101
3. 101
4. 101
5. 10001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had the idea. The problem with your solution is that you already consumed the 1 that you want to use in the next match.

To get around this, use a positive lookahead:

```
/1(0+)(?=1)/
```

The first 1 will be consumed when matched, but the positive lookahead prevents the 2nd "1" from being part of the match, it just *asserts* that the "1" is there

See your example here on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WV1DDY/2)

Answer (score 1):

from `10101010110001`, you can NOT get

```sh
101
101
101
101
10001
```

reason: a char (here is `1`) can NOT be consumed twice.

but can

- possible 1: use `(?<=1)(0+)(?=1)` to get:

```sh
0
0
0
0
000
```

- possible 2: use `(?<=1)(0+)1` to get:

```sh
01
01
01
01
0001
```

- possible 3: use `1(0+)(?=1)` to get:

```
10
10
10
10
1000
```

Note: you can use this online website

https://regexr.com

to debug your regex

[image]

for other tools can refer my (Chinese) tutorial: [正则调试工具 · 应用广泛的超强搜索：正则表达式](https://book.crifan.com/books/super_search_regex/website/regex_experience/regex_debug_tools.html)